# Android Alarm - Activity Sometimes Remains Black After Keyguard Dismissal

Tags: android, android-activity, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-doze

I have an alarm activity, that launches from a service as a Full-Screen Notification Intent. The problem is that **sometimes**, the **activity will remains black** until I turn it off and on again.

Now, although the screen is black, the **views respond to the touch**

If I try to take a screenshot, I suddenly see the activity, and if I turn the screen off and on again, everything is working as expected.

**I can't seem to reproduce this on my debug build**, but it does happen to me on the "production" build from time to time. (Let's say 1/5 times)

It will happen in the morning in between snoozes, but never on the first alarm. (as far as I noticed)

Any idea on what is causing this, or how to reproduce this would help immensely.

**Videos of the weirdness:**

[Responsive black screen](https://youtu.be/jMNsTiFgZxY)

[Turn off, and on again](https://youtu.be/M7CiL3tRNmk)

[Trying to take a screenshot](https://youtu.be/0TF-dx0NXGw)

This is basically how I launch the activity:

```
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NotificationChannels.CHANNEL_ALARM_SERVICE)
...
// set intent
val alarmIntent = Intent(context, AlarmActivity::class.java)
alarmIntent.putExtra(IntentExtras.KEY_ID, alarm.id)
builder.setFullScreenIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, RequestCodes.REQUEST_CODE_ALARM_ACTIVITY, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT), true)
...
startForeground(...)
```

This is how I unlock the screen in the Activity's `onCreate()` method

```
public class ScreenUnlockerUtil {

    public static void unlockScreen(BaseActivity activity) {

        activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            // in addition to flags
            activity.setShowWhenLocked(true);
            activity.setTurnScreenOn(true);
        } else {
            activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        }


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) activity.getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            if (keyguardManager != null) {
                keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(activity, new KeyguardManager.KeyguardDismissCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismissError() {
                        super.onDismissError();
                        ExceptionHandlerWrapper.reportException(new Exception("Keyguard Dismiss Error"));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDismissSucceeded() {
                        super.onDismissSucceeded();
                        Timber.d("Keyguard Dismiss Success");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDismissCancelled() {
                        super.onDismissCancelled();
                        ExceptionHandlerWrapper.reportException(new Exception("Keyguard Dismiss Cancelled"));
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        }


    }
}
```

Edit 1: I'm not seeing any reports from my device regarding keyguard dismissal cancellation or error.

Edit 2: This is all happening on a Pixel 2 XL. Not some random crappy phone.

Comment: I have the same problem Nokia 6.1 Android 9. I am not using dismiss keyguard, so it is clearly related to activity.setShowWhenLocked(true); activity.setTurnScreenOn(true);

Comment: @DominikK Apparently it also doesn't show the Activity when locked on random Samsung devices for our users.

Comment: I am not sure about the samsung devices. Which API level are we talking about on those devices?

Comment: @DominikK Nothing below API 21, but I'm not sure which version those users are running.

Comment: Do you know which types of samsung phones the problem occurs on like on the Galaxy S9, S8, Note,...

Comment: @DominikK I'm not entirely sure at the moment. does it matter - if I don't have any of them at the moment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very strange problem, I couldn't find the exact reason for it. But I could come up with a very stable solution, just add the following parameters to your manifest file and it should work. I have tried it like 15 times and never had the problem again, while I had it 1 out of 5 times with the code solution.

Don't forget to delete the code lines in your onCreate.

```
    <activity android:name=".AlertActivity"
        android:showWhenLocked="true"
        android:turnScreenOn="true">
    </activity>
```

Comment: I hope it works for you too, I still didn't run into the issue again.

Comment: I have, and It's currently rollin in production, but I don't have any way to verify this except waiting to see if anyone is complaining.

Comment: I am already using my app in production for 2 weeks now, it never happened again. Good Luck :)

Comment: Almost a year later the issue never appeard again using this workaround.

Comment: What's the root cause of the issue? Is this issue tracked by Google?

Comment: Is this still a thing nowadays on Android 10+?